# How would larger quadrupeds dodge gunfire and use cover?

Tags: science-based, tactics, firearms

Okay, it's not exactly "dodging", more like running for cover, but you should get the point. There are a handful of creatures in my setting that are quadruped and cover the same size range and build as horses, topping at 180 cm at the withers. They also have human intelligence and can communicate with humans.

One way or another, suppose that such a creature ends up in the middle of a gunfight. The distance between the two sides is usually 300 meters, and this creature is with one of these groups. A horse-sized target is still easier to hit and armor can't protect against the "big guns". While I'm tempted to handwave the issue with EGO weapons and armor (those are for another question), I was curious about what these creatures could do with ordinary equipment and training.

**Namely, what posture would allow them to make the most use of cover and how should they run, when exposed, to minimize their chances of getting hit (i.e: the optimal posture and gait for that)?**

Comment: You are presuming that horse-like quadruped can substantially change its posture and gait while running?

Comment: Since a horse-like being cannot easily do 3-5 second rushes like a human, nor low-crawl, the best strategy is to remain behind the nearest convenient cover and provide support for folks who *can* do 3-5 second rushes and crawl. You give the horse-like being the grenade launcher and lots of ammo.

Comment: Have you researched the tactics of WWI and earlier cavalrymen? Technically, the only difference between that and what you're looking for is the presence of the rider.

Comment: Horses have participated in warfare alongside humans for a very very long time. The horse-and-rider pair does indeed have human level intelligence and can communicate with humans. What did those millions of horse-and-rider pairs do in those hundreds of thousands of battles during those thousands of years? Why don't your quasi-horses do the same?

Comment: @user535733: Horses can't do 3-5 second rushes?  Not in my experience :-)

Comment: @jamesqf since the sides are 300m apart, that implies to me a lack of good cover for rushes.

Comment: I'm really struggling with the "science-based" tag on this question. I feel like we'd need a lot more detail on your race's anatomy.

Comment: @user535733: I thought you were saying that horses physically can't do those 3-5 second rushes.  Believe me, they can.  As for cover, it depends on the terrain.  A well-grown forest, for instance, could have lots of cover in that distance that would shield a horse-sized creature, especially if they stand head-on to the enemy.

Answer (score 2):

**Treat them like light vehicles**

If your creatures are anything like horses, they can't easily duck or kneel, crawl, lean sideways or anything else that humans do to reduce their silhouette / better utilize cover in a firefight. They can, however, carry a lot more than a human, so my suggestion would be to utilize them in support and heavy weapons roles. Being able to bring that much more mortar or missile rounds, bulky electronic equipment or just extra rations sure sounds useful, though they may need a human with them for reloading and/or using the extra equipment.

In terms of positioning and relocating, take a look at tank tactics. Ideally, you want to position yourself behind an obstacle that you can barely look and shoot over, while most of your torso and legs are protected, if something like that is available. If you relocate, your main defenses are speed and covering fire from your team. Don't try to do fancy acrobatics, you just risk falling and breaking your neck / not getting back up quickly for minimal benefit.

If your race is more like a canine or feline and *can* crouch, that somewhat extends the height range of cover that they can utilize, but doesn't fundamentally change their tactics.